# group by String on Power BI works similar to STRING_AGG on SQL Server

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on a Power BI report and using a SQL Server query to return result onto Power BI Desktop like this:

ProductID  CustomerID    ProductName
P1          C11           Bike
P1          C12           Bike
P2          B21           Mountain Bike
P2          B22           Mountain Bike
P2          B23           Mountain Bike

and I want to group by  ProductID and ProductName and then concatenate CustomerID to have result on Power BI report as below:

ProductID   CustomerID       ProductName
P1          C11, C12         Bike
P2          B21, B22,B23         Mountain Bike

I have tried with Dax fuctions such as GROUPBY, ADDCOLUMNS... ON Power BI but has not helped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think, that CONCATENATEX is what you need.
I put only ProductID to my output table and Measure:

[image]

```
Measure 3 = CONCATENATE(
CONCATENATEX(Prod,Prod[CustomerID],",") , CONCATENATEX(VALUES(Prod[ProductName]),Prod[ProductName],",")
)
```

Comment: Hi @msta42a, your solutions has worked for me. Thank you very much